# Table sink doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Rank

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

**Requesting** : Fetch the latest record detail for the customer with latest request time

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT  CUST_ID,  DEPT_NAME,  CREATED_AT 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER(
    PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC) AS row_num
    FROM inputTable
  )
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

**Gives Error:**

```
Table sink '*anonymous_datastream_sink$2*' doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by 
node Rank(strategy=[UndefinedStrategy], rankType=[ROW_NUMBER], rankRange=[rankStart=1, rankEnd=1], partitionBy=[$0], orderBy=[$2 DESC], select=[$0, $1, $2])
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of your query is an update stream (either retractions, or upserting). However, the sink that you try to sink to, doesn't support update streams, but only append streams. So if this is your desired output, then you'll need to change your sink to one that supports update streams.

Comment: Or switch to a sink plus format combination that supports update streams. E.g., the file sink supports update streams if you choose debezium as the format.

Comment: Replaced `TableResult tableResult = tableEnv.executeSql(sqlQuery);` instead of `Table table tableEnv.sqlQuery(sqlQuery);` and  then tableResult.print() now it is working fine but now issue is tableResult is not getting converted to the datastream, the above issue resolved now